# Call to a member function setPath() on a non-object in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

In my Laravel web application, getting error like "Call to a member function setPath() on a non-object" while using pagination. 
My code is

In model,

```
public function scopegetApartments()
    { 

        $list1 = DB::table('properties')->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(1);

    $list = array();
    foreach($list1 as $listeach){
          $imgs = DB::table('property_images')->where('property_id',$listeach->id)->get();;
         $images = array();
        foreach($imgs as $img){
            array_push($images, $img->image);   
          }

          $lists = array(
              'id'=>$listeach->id,
              'name'=>$listeach->name,
              'rent'=>$listeach->rent,
              'shortdescription'=>$listeach->shortdescription,
              'images'=>$images,
          );
           array_push($list, $lists);   
        }
      if(count($list)>0){
            return $list;
        }else{
            return '[]';
        }

    }
```

In view,

```
 $apartmentlist->setPath('serviceapartments');
 echo $apartmentlist->render();
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: How are you sending the data to the view?

Comment: $list1 = DB::table('properties')->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(1);                    return $list1; like this

Comment: When you call the view, you need to pass the data to the view. So, in your controller, you should have a line similar to `return view('myview')->with(['apartmentlist' => $list1]);`. Using the `with()` method lets you set the data that is to be available inside your view.

Comment: yep, My controller view is,  public function serviceapartments() {
        return view('site/serviceapartments',array('apartmentlist'=>Admin::getApartments()));
    }

Comment: Can you show the full code for your `getApartments()` method?

Comment: From the code you've posted, your `scopegetApartments()` method is returning either a string or an array, neither of which are a pagination object. This is the cause of your error. On a side note, this is not the correct way to use model scopes. Scopes are meant to modify a query (like add where clauses or order bys, etc) and return the query builder object, they are not meant to actually execute queries and attempt to return data.

Comment: May i ask, what makes to do so much code ? according to my understanding `laravel ` provides everything you need to handle or create your data

Comment: `$list1` is an object of type: `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` which doesn't have method `setPath` :)

Comment: actually how to resolve that. I don't know how to

Comment: Thank you all. I resolved my problem